# Keeping the dock visible without affecting window size?

Tags: dock, window-manager

Is there any way to keep the dock visible without it affecting the size of windows?

On my MBP 13" I have the dock hidden since it simply takes to much screen real estate, but working with a tablet I feel the need to have it visible at times. And I don't want to hide/unhide with a shortcut, I just want it to show on top of my windows.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but don't forget you can move the dock to the side of your screen, rather than leave it at the bottom. This makes much better use of the screen real estate on most widescreen laptops, IMHO.

Note also that you don't need to use a shortcut to re-show the dock when it's hidden, you just need to move your mouse over it.

Comment: I agree with you that the side is better for widescreens, that's what I'm using when I have to let the dock displace my windows. FYI I've googled some more on this, and I really can't find any solution...

Answer (score 1):

Most apps dont allow that. Some, like excel, allow you to resize the window as you like... even if you dont like the shortcut, you can use it to achieve what you are looking for... although its not very convenient.. you can hide the dock, maximize the window and then unhide it.. it will show ontop of the window.